# `auto x = type{...}` initialization syntax and `explicit` conversion operator - clang vs gcc

Tags: c++, type-conversion, language-lawyer, c++17, explicit

Given this code *(on [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ZfUaA2LqTNRpuBTp))*:

```
struct X
{
    explicit operator int() { return 0; }
};

int main()
{
    auto y = int{X{}};
}
```

And the following compiler options:

> -std=c++1z -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic

---

- `g++` *(tested versions: 7, 6.1, 5.3)* **refuses to compile the code** with the following error

  > error: cannot convert 'X' to 'int' in initialization
- `clang++` *(tested versions: 4, 3.8, 3.6)* **happily compiles the snippet**.

---

**Which compiler is doing the correct thing here?**

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) seems to suggest that the `auto var = type{...}` syntax should trigger an explicit conversion.

Comment: FWIW, MSVC happily compiles too.

Comment: @Danh g++ accepts `int y{X{}}`, which should not be accepted if only implicit conversion where considered (so either this is wrong, or the other one is wrong).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4606.pdf
I think g++ is wrong.

8.6.4 clause 3.7 states:

> — Otherwise, if the initializer list has a single element of type E
>   and either T is not a reference type or its referenced type is
>   reference-related to E, the object or reference is initialized from
>   that element (by copy-initialization for copy-list-initialization, or
>   by direct-initialization for direct-list-initialization); if a
>   narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert the element to
>   T, the program is ill-formed.

Meaning that direct init is used in this case of non-class type, which leads us to 8.6 clause 17.7:

> — Otherwise, if the source type is a (possibly cv-qualified) class
>   type, conversion functions are considered. The applicable conversion
>   functions are enumerated (13.3.1.5), and the best one is chosen
>   through overload resolution (13.3). The user-defined conversion so
>   selected is called to convert the initializer expression into the
>   object being initialized. If the conversion cannot be done or is
>   ambiguous, the initialization is ill-formed.

And finally 13.3.1.5 states that both explicit and implicit conversions are considered for direct initialization:

> — The conversion functions of S and its base classes are considered.
>   Those non-explicit conversion functions that are not hidden within S
>   and yield type T or a type that can be converted to type T via a
>   standard conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.1) are candidate functions. **For
>   direct-initialization, those explicit conversion functions that are
>   not hidden within S and yield type T or a type that can be converted
>   to type T with a qualification conversion (4.5) are also candidate
>   functions**. Conversion functions that return a cv-qualified type are
>   considered to yield the cv-unqualified version of that type for this
>   process of selecting candidate functions. Conversion functions that
>   return “reference to cv2 X” return lvalues or xvalues, depending on
>   the type of reference, of type “cv2 X” and are therefore considered to
>   yield X for this process of selecting candidate functions.

Comment: After carefully reading the standard quotes you posted, it actually seems like `g++` is wrong in this case. I've filed [bug #77976](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77976) and linked to this question and to your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I think I've found older reference to this bug - https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63999